# Elasticsearch Disable Delete indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 1.7.1

After I create my indexes, I do not want to delete existing indexes. (Either manually or by some unintentional execution from my es.)

Is it possible to set any configurations in elasticsearch and restart the service to achieve the above?

I have tried these steps but it is not helping me out.

As for preventing index deletion via a wildcard /* or /_all, one thing i can do is to add the following settings to your config file:

```
action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this by http CORS elasticsearch.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem as you do. But CORS is for HTTP cross domain control. What if the request is sent not from a web but from a client ( say phone app )? How do we prevent Delete from happening?